# replace missing values with other data based on conditions in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I a looking for an efficient way to replace missing data in `data.table`.

When 'description' is "", I want to replace it with the 'description' with the latest date with the same id.  So for `seqs=3`, I want to replace "" with "Red" because `seqs=2` is not "" and is the latest date. `Seqs=4` would just remain "" because there is no other id.

I am working with several million rows and am using `data.table` (so I would love to not convert to the `tidyverse`)

```
set.seed(3)

data.frame(
    seqs = 1:11 ,
    id = c( 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 ,4 , 4, 4 , 5 ) ,
    description = c("Red","Red","","","Blue","Blue","Red","Red","","Red","Blue"),
    dates = sample(  2000:2020, 11, TRUE)
    
)

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach using `last`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

dt[order(id, dates), 
  description := ifelse(description == "", last(description), description), by = id]
dt
    seqs id description dates
 1:    1  1         Red  2004
 2:    2  1         Red  2011
 3:    3  1         Red  2006
 4:    4  2              2003
 5:    5  3        Blue  2007
 6:    6  3        Blue  2010
 7:    7  4         Red  2007
 8:    8  4         Red  2019
 9:    9  4         Red  2009
10:   10  4         Red  2007
11:   11  5        Blue  2015
```

##### Data

```
dt <- structure(list(seqs = 1:11, id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4,
4, 5), description = c("Red", "Red", "Red", "", "Blue", "Blue",
"Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue"), dates = c(2004L, 2011L,
2006L, 2003L, 2007L, 2010L, 2007L, 2019L, 2009L, 2007L, 2015L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Just adding `fifelse`  for those obsessed with speed